# Branch is updated, but I have "Changes not staged for commit" message

Tags: git

I used these commands to upload all of my changes to git server.

- git add . -A
- git commit -m "COMMENT"
- git push

Then, I have the message with `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   content/2014/03/14/pic/photo.JPG
```

I tried `git commit -ma`, but I got the same results.

What might be wrong with this? I use git version 1.9.3.

```
git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

#### Edit

I tried the fresh checkout, but I still have the same issue.

#### Edit2

The photo.JPG directory is renamed into photo.jpg, I use the Mac OS X that is case insensitive.

Comment: Are you running these commands in the root directory of the repository?

Comment: @Jack: Yes, I run where the .git directory is located.

Comment: Have you tried todo a fresh checkout?

Comment: Are `.JPG` files or one of the directories in `content/...` `.gitignore`d?

Comment: @twalberg: The file was renamed, I updated the post.

Comment: Also you can't run (`git commit -ma "your message here"`) as `-m` should follow with it's message straight away. So you might need to change it to (`git commit -am "message here"`) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file was renamed by the same name with uppercased. I had to remove all the files from the repository to push the changes, and then restore the removed file back to repost the changes. Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an old version of Git?

`If no <pathspec> is given when -A option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).`